# Php Slim with SolrClient

Tags: php, solr, slim

I am trying query on my solr server from php slim code but i have problem to use SolrClient. I download solr.so in my php.ini. When i run normal php code, it works correct, However when  I run slim code with SolrClient class, it says "Class 'bla\bla\SolrClient' not found". I know solr.so is module for pure php but I want to know if it is possible to run it with slim?
Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options to use the global [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) for the SolrClient class.

#### Use a fully qualified name (add a backslash)

```
$client = new \SolrClient($options);
```

#### Import a global class (recommended)

```
use SolrClient;

$client = new SolrClient($options);
```